Using docx4j in a spring boot application
I'm using docx4j (docx4j-core 11.3.2) to generate some template-based docx reports in my spring boot application. However, sometimes when 2 threads A and B (2 web calls) are accessing my report generation method, the report content gets mixed up, resulting in some data from A ending up in report B and vice-versa.
The code for fetching the template and initializing the docx4j WordprocessingMLPackage is
    try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(templateName)) {
       WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(inputStream);
       // ...report generation code
    }

I wonder if the issue with thread-safety lies in loading the resource getClass().getResourceAsStream(templateName)), or loading the actual WordprocessingMLPackage WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(inputStream); or maybe it's completely different issue.
I'm using Java 17.

Can you make a minimal reproducible test case Maven project?
